# Color format for monochrome YUYV camera all messed up

Tags: ros, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a see3cam_10CUG camera that I've been using with ROS.

I originally installed uvc_camera and it worked just fine. I then tried to get the libuvc_camera library to work with this camera and went through lots of pain but I couldn't get the camera to work due to errors.

I then tried going back to uvc_camera and now my image looks like this:
[image: image description]

Is there any way I can change the pixel format for uvc_camera to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266512/color-format-for-monochrome-yuyv-camera-all-messed-up./) by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2017-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-07-16**:
That kinda looks like a raw bayer-pattern image from a color image sensor, before debayering.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-17**:
@psammut: could I ask you to attach your image to this post directly (instead of hosting it on `imgur`)? I've given you enough karma to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so I feel a little stupid about this one.

I first tried the uvc_camera library and ran it with this launch file and it worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Camera -->
  <node ns="/camera" pkg="uvc_camera" type="uvc_camera_node" name="camera">
    <param name="device" value="/dev/video0"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I then tried another uvc camera library that gives more access to the see3cam_10CUG's exposure parameters, which is here: https://github.com/dgossow/see3cam

Problem here is two fold. That special see3cam library is actually for the see3ceam_10CUG_C  camera, which is the color version, hence why it was giving me the weird bayer encoding for the monochrome image.

I then deleted this package and tried to go back to using the uvc_camera library. To my horror I'd get the same messed up picture. The problem here is that the see3cam library uses the same package name as uvc_camera, and even though I had deleted the source and ran catkin_make, the binaries were still in the build folder and they were getting loaded when I was trying to load the regular uvc_camera driver. So, I deleted the build folder, rebuilt without the see3cam package and everything worked and went back to normal.

I wish libuvc_camera worked with this camera, so I could get on the fly exposure control, but I spent a day on trying to get it to work and couldn't so uvc_camera it is.

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) with karma: 258 on 2017-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0